# How to hide Oracle Apex Database Application Code After Publish

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-apex-5

With Oracle APEX, after I finished developing application I want to publish it to customer on its LAN network, when I export file I choose Build Status Override: **Read Application Only** 
But when I want to import it, it can be changed to **Read and Build Application**
and -in other hand- its Build status can be changed to **Read and Build Application** from instance administration even if I imported it as **Read Application Only**.

I want to import Application in a way that no one can modify it or see its code.

Any Help Please ?!...

Comment: If you let the customer install it on their kit, it's under their control. If you want to retain control, you need to host it yourself.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot prevent customers from **seeing** the code of your APEX application as it is all stored in plain text in tables.  What you can do is put most of your code into packages which can be [wrapped](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/wrap.htm#LNPLS016).  (Mind you, you can get software to unwrap package code anyway, so this isn't bulletproof.)

Answer (score 2):

What you are describing is the APEX Runtime only install.

The documentation explains it here:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E71588_01/HTMIG/converting-between-runtime-and-full-development-environments.htm#HTMIG29458

The short version is on the runtime only database run this script.

```
$ sql / as sysdba
SQL>@apxdevrm.sql
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, BUT can't any one export my application using any oracle API if I installed only APEX Runtime ?..

Comment: Yes there's no way to stop that. Be sure to put all your plsql in packages and wrap them to help some.